# I want to show all commits before HEAD and show all branch reference each commits

Tags: git

I want to show all commits before HEAD and show all branch reference each commits.

`git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all`

result:

```
* 48879e9 (HEAD -> testlog) test git branch
| * 5b197c5 (master) test amend  before commit is  eighth commit
| * 57484e1 eighth commit
| * 90f8daa seventh commit
| * 185410d sixth commit
| * 90864ad sixth commit
| * 5ce7d48 fourth commit
|/  
* d0e380b third commit
* def8327 second commit
* 6413042 first commit
```

Now I at the commit '48879e9'

I type: 
`git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate testlog`

Result:

```
    * commit 48879e9 (testlog)
| Author: 中文姓名 <chinalilonglong@sina.com>
| Date:   Thu May 24 15:53:05 2018 +0800
| 
|     test git branch
| 
* commit d0e380b
| Author: 中文姓名 <chinalilonglong@sina.com>
| Date:   Fri May 18 11:29:11 2018 +0800
| 
|     third commit
| 
* commit def8327
| Author: 中文姓名 <chinalilonglong@sina.com>
| Date:   Fri May 18 11:28:36 2018 +0800
| 
|     second commit
| 
* commit 6413042
  Author: 中文姓名 <chinalilonglong@sina.com>
  Date:   Fri May 18 11:16:43 2018 +0800
```

How to show the commit before current HEAD.

How to show all branches reference each commit in the parenthesis.

like this:

```
* commit 48879e9 (testlog)
| Author: 中文姓名 <chinalilonglong@sina.com>
| Date:   Thu May 24 15:53:05 2018 +0800
| 
|     test git branch
| 
* commit d0e380b (master)
| Author: 中文姓名 <chinalilonglong@sina.com>
| Date:   Fri May 18 11:29:11 2018 +0800
| 
|     third commit
| 
* commit def8327
| Author: 中文姓名 <chinalilonglong@sina.com>
| Date:   Fri May 18 11:28:36 2018 +0800
| 
|     second commit
| 
* commit 6413042
  Author: 中文姓名 <chinalilonglong@sina.com>
  Date:   Fri May 18 11:16:43 2018 +0800
```

I changed the `* commit d0e380b` to `* commit d0e380b (master)`.

By doing this, I can hunt which branch that this current branch from quickly.

Comment: just remove the `--all` Switch at the end? (`git log --graph --decorate --oneline`)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle  Remove the `--all` doesn't show the reference for each commit.

Comment: what about `git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate`?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Thank you very much. The result isn't correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A branch pointer is more or less just a pointer to a specific commit.
The `--decorate` option of `git log` will print the branch ref to the specifific commit which the branch refers to.

Your `master` branch ref points to `5b197c5`. Hence, it will not be printed when you do `git log` for the `testlog` branch, because `5b197c5` is not a part of the `testlog` branch.

**Alternative approach 1**

If you just want to see in the log at which point the `testlog` branch diverged from master, you could try doing:
`git log $(git merge-base master testlog)^..testlog`
This will not yield the same result as you desire. But if you run that command, it will print the log for commits on `testlog` branch, starting from the latest common commit between the two branches. (So you know that the last commit printed by that command exist in both `testlog` and `master` branch).

**Alternative approach 2**

The output will look quite different, but you could try using the `git show-branch` command. Example (as a picture, since it's easier on the eyes with correct colors):

[image]

Here, you can see that the latest common commit between `branch3` and `master` is `e828d00`. All commits on `branch1` exist in `master` branch. `729edd5` is the latest commit which is common for all four branches. etc.

The output may become a bit messy if there are too many branches though.